# How to compile lapack with rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, lapack

I am trying to use lapack with rust. Therefore I started with the example from the rust crates https://crates.io/crates/lapack

My Cargo.toml file looks like

```
enter [package]
name = "matmul"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


[dependencies]
lapack = "0.19.0"
                 

[profile.dev]
opt-level = 0



[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
```

When trying to compile I get the following error

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" 
 then there is a file list
"-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: ~/programs/Rust/matmul/target/debug/deps/matmul-9ca04f70dc77cf78.3ybb6pvq2ip54xxg.rcgu.o: in function `lapack::dsyev':
          ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lapack-0.19.0/src/lapack-sys.rs:29108: undefined reference to `dsyev_'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `matmul` due to previous error
```

Am I missing some dependencies or why does this code not compile?

Comment: Have you installed lapack? The lapack crate is just a wrapper, meaning it let's you interact with the lapack library, but it's not the *actual* library.

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes lapack and blas is installed. I am able to use it in c++ and Fortran. I tested this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your gnu linker is stuck - not uncommon. I see cc, so I’m guessing this is a Cray. You need to make sure you have the correct modules loaded and possibly figure out where lapack lives. Typically, this is cray-libsci (if I remember correctly). Then, you may need to tell cargo explicitly as suggested in the error message: `cargo:rustc-link-lib`.

Does that help?